# Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app) error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have put my config info from my firebase into the index.js. I also did firebase.initializeApp(config) here.

I'm on the Login page. I try to do firebase.auth().signinwithemailandpassword.
When I put correct email and password, I don't have any error but when I put wrong email or password, it gives me the error saying "Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)" I tried putting firebase config here and initializeApp. I put a catch around it but seems like it doesn't work... How should I solve this issue.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the all has already initialized, the solution is to check if the app was created before calling initialize.

For example:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const config = {...};

// Here we check if we app initialzied app before initializing the same app again
!firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app();
```